# How do you rotate a point in the complex plane by $\theta$ radians?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let's say you had a point $(a,b)$ on the complex plane. If I wanted to rotate this point $\theta$ radians around point $(c,d)$ to $(a',b')$, how would I find $a'$ and $b'$?

I'm not sure on how to get a formula for this. When rotating a complex point around the origin, I know that multiplying by fractions $i$ in exponential form works, but I'm not sure if that's the same for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that you rotate a point $z$ around a center $w$ an angle $\theta$ to obtain $z'$.

Then

$$z'=w+e^{i\theta}(z-w)$$

The background idea is translating the $z$ and the center in order the center to be the origin, doing the rotation there, and then moving back the obtained point.

Perhaps the formula
$$\frac{z'-w}{z-w}=e^{i\theta}$$
is a bit clearer.

Comment: So, do you subtract the respective coordinates of z and w?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you can consider a traslate in the origin:
$$\rho= \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$$ and $$\theta'=\arg[(a-c)+i(b-d)] $$
so now it is easy to sum $\alpha=\theta+\theta'$ and you can come back:
$$a'=c+\rho\sin[\alpha]$$
and
$$b'=d+\rho\cos[\alpha]$$